# IntegrityError at /contact NOT NULL constraint failed: first_contact.fname

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

getting an integrity error while running this code. Also after some modifications in models.datefield(), it went well but the data base was not storing the entries and the table was empty when the forms were filled.

*models.py*

```
# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=122) 
    desc = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12) 
    date = models.DateField()
```

here is my *views.py*

```
from datetime import datetime
from first.models import Contact
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
    # return HttpResponse("This is our home page")

def about(request):
     return render(request, 'about.html')
    #return HttpResponse("This is our about page")

def services(request):
     return render(request, 'services.html')
     #return HttpResponse("This is our services page")
    

def contact(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
          fname  = request.POST.get('fname')
          lname  = request.POST.get('lname')
          desc  = request.POST.get('desc')
          city  = request.POST.get('city')
          phone  = request.POST.get('phone')
          contact = Contact(fname=fname, lname=lname, desc=desc, city=city, phone=phone, 
 date=datetime.today())
          contact.save()
     return render(request, 'contact.html')
     #return HttpResponse("This is our contact page")
```

Comment: Show the html for the form used in `contact`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign `datetime` object to the `DateField`. `DateField` will only accept a `date` object.

`datetime.today()` still returns a `datetime` object, but the time will be set to all zeros to indicate the beginning of the day. If you really don't care about storing the time, use `date.today()` instead. If you want to store the time information, convert your field into `DateTimeField`.